# Load an RDD into hive

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to load an RDD (k=table_name, v=content) into a partitioned hive table (year,month, day) with pyspark in spark version 1.6.x

The whole while trying to use the logic of this SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE db_schema.%FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION% DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (year=%YEAR%, month=%MONTH%, day=%DAY%);LOAD DATA INTO TABLE db_schema.%FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION% PARTITION (year=%YEAR%, month=%MONTH%, day=%DAY%);
```

Could someone please give some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1, 'cat', '2016-12-20'), (2, 'dog', '2016-12-21')])
df = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema=['id', 'val', 'dt'])
df.write.saveAsTable(name='default.test', format='orc', mode='overwrite', partitionBy='dt')
```

Using **enableHiveSupport()** and **df.write.saveAsTable()**